# Plotting list data of cross product of field vectors

Tags: plotting, vector-calculus, products, vector

I have some experimental data points of electric `Ey(t, value)` and magnetic field `Hz(t, value)`. I am trying to calculate the cross product of

```
CrossProduct[Last /@ Ey, Last /@ Hz]
```

After that, I tried  to plot by

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{First /@ Ey, Last /@ Ey, Last /@ Hz}], Joined -> True].
```

But it's not working.

```
Ey(t,value)={{545136.47, -10299.3}, {545272.75, 12749.9}, {545136.47, -10299.3}, 
  {545272.75, 12749.9}, {545409.04, 
  34182.2}, {545545.32, 52240.2}, {545681.61, 
  65501.5}, {545817.89, 72989.9}, {545954.18, 
  74243.1}, {546090.46, 69331.9}, {546226.74, 
  58833.2}, {546363.03, 43760.6}, {546499.31, 25462.}}

 Hz(t,value)= {{435000.19, -28.325425}, {545136.47, 
 32.645681}, {545272.75, 89.460979}, {545409.04, 
 137.48363}, {545545.32, 172.95153}, {545681.61, 
 193.26996}, {545817.89, 197.18915}, {545954.18, 
 184.85647}, {546090.46, 157.74581}, {546226.74, 
 118.47856}, {546363.03, 70.558464}}
```

Comment: It looks like some t values in Ey do not exist in Bz and vice-versa, this may contribute some issues you have yet to encounter.

Answer (score 0):

First, Ey has at the beginning and the end one data point more than Hz. Eliminate these:

```
Ey = {{545136.47, -10299.3}, {545272.75, 
    12749.9}, {545136.47, -10299.3}, {545272.75, 12749.9}, {545409.04,
     34182.2}, {545545.32, 52240.2}, {545681.61, 65501.5}, {545817.89,
     72989.9}, {545954.18, 74243.1}, {546090.46, 69331.9}, {546226.74,
     58833.2}, {546363.03, 43760.6}, {546499.31, 25462.}};
Ey = Ey[[2 ;; -2]];

Hz = {{435000.19, -28.325425}, {545136.47, 32.645681}, {545272.75, 
    89.460979}, {545409.04, 137.48363}, {545545.32, 
    172.95153}, {545681.61, 193.26996}, {545817.89, 
    197.18915}, {545954.18, 184.85647}, {546090.46, 
    157.74581}, {546226.74, 118.47856}, {546363.03, 70.558464}};
```

Then you can calculate the cross products:

```
MapThread[ Cross[{0, #1, 0}, {0, 0, #2}] &, {Ey[[All, 2]], Hz[[All, 2]]}]
(*{{-361146., 0., 0.}, {-336228., 0., 0.}, {1.14062*10^6, 0., 
  0.}, {4.69949*10^6, 0., 0.}, {9.03502*10^6, 0., 0.}, {1.26595*10^7, 
  0., 0.}, {1.43928*10^7, 0., 0.}, {1.37243*10^7, 0., 
  0.}, {1.09368*10^7, 0., 0.}, {6.97047*10^6, 0., 0.}, {3.08768*10^6, 
  0., 0.}}*)
```

And plot E and H:

```
ListLinePlot[Ey]
ListLinePlot[{Hz}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The times are misaligned, it might be helpful to show OP how to ensure these are aligned.

Comment: @Huber, I want to plot  the cross product of Ey[[All, 2]], Hz[[All, 2]]}]

Comment: Use ListVectorPlot3D or ListSliceVectorPlot3D